# Which program does Docker use to execute this format of CMD?

Tags: linux, docker

The [documentation](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#cmd) of Docker says:

> If you want to run your `<command>` without a shell then you must express the command as a JSON array and give the full path to the executable. This array form is the preferred format of CMD. Any additional parameters must be individually expressed as strings in the array:
>
> ```
> FROM ubuntu
> CMD ["/usr/bin/wc","--help"]
> ```

If `CMD ["/usr/bin/wc","--help"]` will be executed without a shell, then how is it executed? Which program does Docker use to run it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

None. That's the format [`exec`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/exec.3.html) system call uses.

That's also how any shell, and any other program, runs other programs.

Comment: Thanks for such a great answer, just one last question: Does Docker make that `exec` system call?

Comment: @Hayk Yes. First it forks its own process (ie. splits a 2nd similar process out of it), then in that 2nd process makes an `exec` syscall to replace that process with the one specified. It may sound weird at first, but that's how all processes are created in the Linux world. With the exception of the first one, of course.